# Getting a refresh token,Google

Tags: php, token, access-token, google-api-php-client

i have seen many post regarding Google-login-api refresh token but whatever method i try it doesn't work and won't fetch me a new token.

This is my code that throws an exception when it doesn't get a refresh token.

> The OAuth 2.0 access token has expired and a refresh token is not available. Refresh tokens are not returned for responses that were auto-approved

```
// Check if the token is set to expire in the next 30 seconds
// (or has already expired).
if ($this->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  if ($this->assertionCredentials) {
    $this->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
  } else {
    $this->client->getLogger()->debug('OAuth2 access token expired');
    if (! array_key_exists('refresh_token', $this->token)) {
      $error = "The OAuth 2.0 access token has expired,"
              ." and a refresh token is not available. Refresh tokens"
              ." are not returned for responses that were auto-approved.";

      $this->client->getLogger()->error($error);
      throw new Google_Auth_Exception($error);
    }
    $this->refreshToken($this->token['refresh_token']);
  }
}

$this->client->getLogger()->debug('OAuth2 authentication');

// Add the OAuth2 header to the request
$request->setRequestHeaders(
    array('Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->token['access_token'])
);

return $request;
 }

    /**
  * Fetches a fresh access token with the given refresh token.
  * @param string $refreshToken
  * @return void
 */
 public function refreshToken($refreshToken)
 {
$this->refreshTokenRequest(
    array(
      'client_id' => $this->client->getClassConfig($this, 'client_id'),
      'client_secret' => $this->client->getClassConfig($this, 'client_secret'),
      'refresh_token' => $refreshToken,
      'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
      'approval_prompt' =>'force'
    )
);
 }

  /**
  * Fetches a fresh access token with a given assertion token.
  * @param Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials $assertionCredentials optional.
  * @return void
  */
  public function refreshTokenWithAssertion($assertionCredentials = null)
 {
if (!$assertionCredentials) {
  $assertionCredentials = $this->assertionCredentials;
}

$cacheKey = $assertionCredentials->getCacheKey();

if ($cacheKey) {
  // We can check whether we have a token available in the
  // cache. If it is expired, we can retrieve a new one from
  // the assertion.
  $token = $this->client->getCache()->get($cacheKey);
  if ($token) {
    $this->setAccessToken($token);
  }
  if (!$this->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    return;
  }
}

$this->client->getLogger()->debug('OAuth2 access token expired');
$this->refreshTokenRequest(
    array(
      'grant_type' => 'assertion',
      'assertion_type' => $assertionCredentials->assertionType,
      'assertion' => $assertionCredentials->generateAssertion(),
    )
);

if ($cacheKey) {
  // Attempt to cache the token.
  $this->client->getCache()->set(
      $cacheKey,
      $this->getAccessToken()
  );
}
 }
```

How do i get a refresh token for my api?

**Files:** http://codepad.org/zo8wLJEE (Full Oauth2 File)